# How to Pass the twitter data-widget-id dynamically from variable in Angular 2 and above

Tags: angular, twitter

I wanted to Embed to twitter widget in my angular app, however, the data-widget-id required in twitter is stored in the database when I pass the widget id from variable twitter component does not render if I pass the widget id hard code string then twitter widget loads successfully

```
<!-- Works -->
<a  class="twitter-timeline" data-widget-id="973470934035202049"></a>

<!-- Does not work -->
<a  class="twitter-timeline" attr.data-widget-id="{{twitterWigetId}}"></a>
```

Here is and Example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxavf8?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two problems. You use `twitterWigetId` in your markup but your defined attribute is `witterWigetId`. Also, change it to `string` from `number`

I, also, recommend you define `twttr` at the top of your class so that your IDE does not give error.

`declare var twttr: any;`

Check out following code

```
import { Component , AfterViewInit , ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

declare var twttr: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: ' <a  class="twitter-timeline" [attr.data-widget-id]="twitterWidgetId"></a>'
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    twitterWidgetId = '973470934035202049';

    ngAfterViewInit() {
       twttr.widgets.load();          
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried above solution but does not work, I have provided link to the online demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxavf8?file=app%2Fapp.component.html can you please make the necessary changes there

Comment: @FahadRehman I’m glad it works. Can you mark my answer as accepted since it solved your problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best way to integrate any twitter widgets in Angular2
You can easily pass widget-id in options
Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-twitter-widgets

Install package

```
npm install --save ngx-twitter-widgets
```

Import NgxTwitterWidgetsModule to NgModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgxTwitterWidgetsModule } from "ngx-twitter-widgets";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxTwitterWidgetsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Use ngx-twitter-timeline tag to your template

```
<ngx-twitter-timeline
  [source]="{sourceType: 'profile', screenName: 'TwitterDev'}" 
  [options]="{height: '400'}" >
</ngx-twitter-timeline>
```